# How to Copy Table Row with clone in jquery and create new Unique Ids for the controls

Tags: jquery

How to Copy Table Row with clone in jquery and create new Unique Ids for the controls.Clone will acually copy data also .i don't want data to be copied .

The table row contains the following information:

```
<tr> 
     <td><input type="text" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle"></td> 
     <td><input type="text" id="txtLink" name="txtLink"></td> 
</tr>
```

i need to create unique ids for all the new rows ,like txtTitle1, link1 ,Title2,link2  etc

Comment: Can you show some example markup?

Comment: Can you clone the row and then change the data?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() ​​​{
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
  }).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;
})​;​
```

This would empty the values for new rows and give them unique IDs starting with txtTitle1, txtTile2, etc.

[You ca give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BE5Lr/).  If you needed to change the `name` too I'd pass an object to [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to keep it a bit cleaner, like this:

```
var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() {
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).attr({
      'id': function(_, id) { return id + i },
      'name': function(_, name) { return name + i },
      'value': ''               
    });
  }).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;
});​
```

[You can try that version out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BE5Lr/1/).

Comment: This is beautiful JavaScript that almost moved me to tears. Also I had no idea you could use `function(_,id)` inside an attribute assignment like that. Thank you one million times over.

Comment: function(_,id) is glory. Thanks for that

Comment: What about events related to for example the onclicks?

Comment: That is some seriously sexy coding there!

Comment: My table has a header row so I needed the second TR. `$("table tr").eq(1).clone()....` works like a charm!