# Customizing JQuery Cloned row attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been researching the JQuery way to add table rows dynamically. One excellent thread is: [How to Copy Table Row with clone in jquery and create new Unique Ids for the controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504499/how-to-copy-table-row-with-clone-in-jquery-and-create-new-unique-ids-for-the-cont), with the last example being the one I am targeting in this post.

[I have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/EwQUW/1/) giving an example of what I am trying to do. This fiddle does not work exactly yet, but I am working on it,

The main issue I am having is getting the table row copy to set different types of column elements id and default values, and even row attributes. In essence, how do I extend this to be more robust.

Thanks to Nick Craver, I am trying to use this:

```
// do Add row options
$("#Add").click(function() {

    var rowCount = $('#secondaryEmails >tbody >tr').length;
    var i = rowCount + 1;
    alert('rowCount: ' + rowCount + ', new row: ' + i);
    $("#secondaryEmails >tbody tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) {
                return id + i
            },
           'name': function(_, name) {
                return name + i
            },
            'value': ''
        });
    }).end().appendTo("#secondaryEmails >tbody");
});
```

which will copy and insert a row nicely, but if I have a row with a radio button, input box, and select list, I cannot figure out how to tell it to set the default value of each element depending on the type of element. I am trying to use a template row, but that means I need to set the `style:display` attribute on the row from `none` to `table-cell`. Again, how?

Please see the fiddle mentioned previously for a working example.

Comment: your fiddle didn't have jquery imported. http://jsfiddle.net/EwQUW/2/

Comment: I had just created the account and entered the code before posting here. I forgot to set that setting. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now showing the row: http://jsfiddle.net/EwQUW/5/

You would want to use `.show()` on the element to show it, which effectively sets the style to `display:block` instead of `display:none;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/EwQUW/3/

```
 // do Add button options
$("#Add").click(function() {
    var i = ($('#secondaryEmails >tbody >tr').length)+1;
    $("#secondaryEmails >tbody tr:first").clone().find("input,select").each(function() {
        //if(this).(':radio').
        $(this).attr({
            'id': function(_, id) {
                return id + i;
            },
            'name': function(_, name) {
                if($(this).attr("type") == "radio")
                    return name;
                return name + i;
            },
            'value': ''
        });
    }).end().appendTo("#secondaryEmails >tbody").show();
});
// do update button options
$("#update").click(function() {
    // find and display selected row data
    alert('in Update');
    var rowCount = $('#secondaryEmails >tbody >tr').length;

});
// do row double click options
// do row selected by either focusing on email or ship type elements
```

Comment: I have another question or 2 on this. I am hoping that this will be the last for awhile. In the above mentioned fiddle, I have a radio button that cannot have its name changed because it is part of a group. How can I selectively tell this script that to not change the name portion if it is a radio button?

Comment: And lastly, for some reason the <Select> list is not getting either its ID or Name updated... any ideas why? (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/EwQUW/8/)

Comment: @radi8 - Check my edited answer for your next part of the question.