# add a new row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

I want to add a new row to my table on a change event.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$('#CourseID').change(function() {
    $('#CourseListTable > tr > td:last').append('<td>...</td>');
});
```

Here is my table:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>    
<table id="CourseListTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Course ID</th>
        <th>Course Section</th>
        <th>Level</th>            
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><select name="CourseID" id="CourseID"></select></td>
        <td><select name="CourseSection" id="CourseSection"></select></td>
        <td><select name="Level" id="Level"></select></td>            
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am not able to get this to work. I am missing something over here can anyone let me know where my error lies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add `thead` and `tbody` sections to your table, you could just append the new row to the tbody... Also, I just realized you are appending a cell. Did you want to append a cell or a row?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You mention append Row but in your code you are appending just cells.

If you need to actually append a full row, try this:

```
$('#CourseID').change(function() {
    $('<tr/>').append('<td>...</td>').insertAfter('#CourseListTable tr:last');
});
```

Comment: Looks like its appending a row, but it just adds three dots '...' to the new row. I want to display all the three selects I have in the td in the new row.

Comment: The dots in the example I have provided are just as space fillers. You should replace that with the HTML you want to append.

Comment: Also on note, the ID for a HTML element shuold be unique across the page. Make sure you don't create html elements with same id

Answer (score 6):

This line:

```
$('#CourseListTable > tr > td:last').append('<td>...</td>');
```

appends a TD (`<td>...</td>`) to an existing TD (`td:last`); you want to append it to a TR, eg.

```
$('#CourseListTable > tr').append('<td>...</td>');
```

Of course, you mentioned wanting to add a new *row*, in which case you shouldn't be appending a `<td>` at all, you should be appending a `<tr>` (and you should append it to the table, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#CourseID').change(function() {
    $('#CourseListTable > tbody > tr:eq(1)').append('<td>...</td>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new row you have to add a `tr`

```
$('#CourseListTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>...</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `after` instead, `append` will append the element inside the `tr`.

```
$('#CourseID').change(function() {
    $('#CourseListTable tr:last').after('<tr><td>test</td><td>test</td><td>test</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this:

[Customizing JQuery Cloned row attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835342/customizing-jquery-cloned-row-attributes)

It lets you clone, append and then customize each cell.. very flexible.