# How to avoid duplicate id when cloning elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be a good strategy for dealing with duplicated id's when using jquery clone method? For example, i need to clone a button in a unspecified number of times. Which is the best way for generating unique id's and keep track of it?

```
<div id="button-pool">
    <button id="bt1" class="return">Button</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bt1").click(function(){
       var newButton = $(this).clone();
        $("#button-pool").append(newButton);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uv95nzrk/

Comment: Have you considered assigning all your buttons a common class and attaching the click function that way instead of through ids?

Comment: utilize classes like @UtopiaLtd said.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone in JQuery and adding unique IDs for each](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711970/clone-in-jquery-and-adding-unique-ids-for-each)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [**Attribute StartsWith Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to see how many buttons with that same id naming style already exists:

```
"button[id^='bt']"
```

And append it increasing it by `1`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bt1").click(function(){
        var idcount = $("button[id^='bt']").length;
        
        var newButton = $(this).clone();
        newButton.attr("id", "bt" + (idcount + 1));
        $("#button-pool").append(newButton);
    });
});
```

```css
.return{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#bt1{
    border: 2px solid navy;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button-pool">
    <button id="bt1" class="return">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilizing Classes to acheive this is a much better strategy, bloating your DOM with generated ID's is not really a great idea. (Poor Design Practice)

```
<div id="button-pool">
    <button class="btns" custom-attr='1' class="return">Button</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btns").click(function(){
       var newButton = $(this).clone();
        newButton.attr('custom-attr', parseInt(newButton.attr('custom-attr'))+1);
        $("#button-pool").append(newButton);
    });
});
```

You can also use custom attributes to track your buttons so that they're still unique from one another, but they don't really need to have ID's

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple counter, and append it to the button id. This counter should be inside a closure not to interfere with the rest of the scripts in your page;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var btnId = 1; // This is a safe place, inside a closure (function body).
  $("#bt1").click(function(){
      var newButton = $(this).clone();
      newButton.attr('id','btn' + btnId);
      btnId++; // Increment after creating each new button
      $("#button-pool").append(newButton);
  });
});
```

You can also create the buttons without ids, unless you really need them. Why do you need to keep track of them?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
var count = 0;
$("#bt1").click(function(){
   var newButton = $(this).clone();
    newButton.attr("id", "bt"+count);
    $("#button-pool").append(newButton);
    count++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('click','#bt1',function(){
       var newButton = $(this).clone();
        $("#button-pool").append(newButton);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

easy answer is use `class` instead of `id`.