# How to assign unique id and href to a pair of cloned objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

That's what I have:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-product-wrap-inner">
  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#1" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <button class="btn-copy-group"></button>

  <div class="collapse" id="1"></div>

  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#2" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <div class="collapse" id="2"></div>

  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#3" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <div class="collapse" id="3"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
init: function () {
      var that = this;

      this.$productEdit..on('click', '.btn-copy-group', function(){
          var $targetTable = $(this).closest('.table-product-wrap-inner'),
              $clonedTable = $targetTable.clone(),
              $clonTableId = $clonedTable.removeAttr('data-product-link-group-id'),
              $groupName = $clonedTable.find('.product-group-link-name'),
              $linkName = $clonedTable.find('.product-link-title'),
              $idLink = $clonedTable.find('.product-link-id');

          $targetTable.after($clonTableId);
          $groupName.val($groupName.val() + " Копия");
          $linkName.val($linkName.val() + " Копия");
          $idLink.val('');
        })
}
```

On click `button` with class `.btn-copy-group` i duplicate `div` with class `.table-product-wrap-inner` under original, but i also need to assign uniqeu `id` and same `href` for each pair of link in `table` and `div` next to it.

For unique ID i have a function:

```
getUniqueId: (function () {
      var i = 1;

      function getUniqueId() {
        return i += 1;
      }

      return getUniqueId;
    }())
```

and i use this to assign inique `id` when i clone one pair of `table` + `div`:

```
var newId = 'copy' + that.getUniqueId();

$clonedTable.after($targetDiv.clone().attr('id', newId));
$clonedTable.find('[data-toggle=collapse]').attr('href', '#' + newId);
```

So i dont know how to use this when we have a lot of pairs (there may be a different numbers of pairs) `table` + `div`.
The end result (after duplicate) should be something like this:

```
<div class="table-product-wrap-inner">
  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#1" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <button class="btn-copy-group"></button>

  <div class="collapse" id="1"></div>

  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#2" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <div class="collapse" id="2"></div>

  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#3" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <div class="collapse" id="3"></div>
</div>
<!-- COPY -->
<div class="table-product-wrap-inner">
  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#copy1" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <button class="btn-copy-group"></button>

  <div class="collapse" id="copy1"></div>

  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#copy2" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <div class="collapse" id="copy2"></div>

  <table class="table-product">
    <a href="#copy3" data-toggle="collapse"></a>
  </table>

  <div class="collapse" id="copy3"></div>
</div>
```

If user click `<button class="btn-copy-group">` in duplicated `<div class="table-product-wrap-inner">` he will get another copy with unique `id` etc etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711970/clone-in-jquery-and-adding-unique-ids-for-each

Comment: Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead. http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Thx but that works only if i clone one object per click with one ID. I use similar function for clone one pair of table+div. But i need assing a unique id for each par of tabble+div because i duplicate several of them per click. And seems i cant avoid .clone().

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique id with:

```js
function uniqueID() {
  return "id-" + Date.now();
}
var id = uniqueID();
console.log(id);
```

The **Date.now()** method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00. This should give you a fairly save unique id even if you clone more than 1 item at a time.