# Add new select with unqiue name onchange of previous select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select, onchange

I have a job that requires several hundred `select` elements on a page. I want to show each `select` dynamically as the previous is changed. I have a working version in which I put all the `select` elements in the markup, and then used a simple function to hide them all and show only the first. Then on change of each `select` the next is added.

This works just fine, but is obviously not ideal. I don't want to put 500 `select` items in the markup and hide them all for no reason, and my JS function would be 1500 lines long. Plus that would make me feel silly.

**How can I automate this process with JS?**

I do not need each `select` to have a unique `id`, but I do need each `select` to have a unique and incremented `name`. Is this possible? I have a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06zvyu1s/1/).

***HTML:***

```
<select name="select-one" class="hidden" id="one">
   <option value="">not this one</option>
   <option value="">pick this one</option>
</select>

<select name="select-two" class="hidden" id="two">
   <option value="">not this one</option>
   <option value="">pick this one</option>
</select>

<select name="select-three" class="hidden" id="three">
   <option value="">not this one</option>
   <option value="">pick this one</option>
</select>

<select name="select-four" class="hidden" id="four">
   <option value="">not this one</option>
   <option value="">pick this one</option>
</select>
```

***JS:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.hidden').hide();
  $('#one').show();

  $('#one').change(function(){
     $('#two').show();
  });
  $('#two').change(function(){
     $('#three').show();
  });
  $('#three').change(function(){
     $('#four').show();
  });
  // and so forth...

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**:

```
<select class="hidden" id="one" name='name_0'>
   <option value="">not this one</option>
   <option value="">pick this one</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
$('body').append($(this).clone(true))
})
```

**Result**:

[image]

Note we are using the overload of the clone() method. This means **event handlers and data** will be copied along with the elements. So whatever event handler you attached to the original select gets cloned.

If you want to **increment the name** just use a **counter** and add the **attribute** after the clone:

```
cnt=0;
$('select').on('change', function() {
cnt++
$('body').append($(this).clone(true).attr('name', 'name_' + cnt))
})
```

[image]

Comment: This does solve my problem in part, but I need each new select to have a unique and incremented `name` property

Comment: @ATomCalledStu maybe this can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711970/clone-in-jquery-and-adding-unique-ids-for-each

Comment: @ATomCalledStu see addition to bottom of answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
const createSelect = index => `
<select name="select-${index}" class="hidden select" data-index=${index}>
   <option value="">not this one</option>
   <option value="">pick this one</option>
</select>
`;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Generate 100 selects
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    $("body").append(createSelect(i));
  }

  // Show first select
  $(`.select[data-index='0']`).show();

  $('.select').on('change', function() {
    // Store index of a select currently changed
    const index = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);

    // Show next select
    $(`.select[data-index='${index + 1}']`).show();
  });
});
```