# What is the `_` in #using-memoizing-selectors example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, reselect

Was looking at examples on `reselect`'s `createSelector` at https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors.

What is the `_` in `(_,isDone) => isDone`?

Is it `lodash`? How did it get injected? Was it injected by the library?

```js
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector = () =>
  createSelector(
    state => state.todos,
    (_, isDone) => isDone,
    (todos, isDone) => todos.filter(todo => todo.isDone === isDone).length
  )

export const TodoCounterForIsDoneValue = ({ isDone }) => {
  const selectNumOfTodosWithIsDone = useMemo(
    makeNumOfTodosWithIsDoneSelector,
    []
  )

  const numOfTodosWithIsDoneValue = useSelector(state =>
    selectNumOfTodosWithIsDone(state, isDone)
  )

  return <div>{numOfTodosWithIsDoneValue}</div>
}

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Number of done todos:</span>
      <TodoCounterForIsDoneValue isDone={true} />
      <span>Number of unfinished todos:</span>
      <TodoCounterForIsDoneValue isDone={false} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is just an unused parameter, since the code is only reading from the second parameter, naming the first would throw a lint warning for unused variables. Naming as `_` will prevent the behavior. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406823/underscore-as-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Thanks. I guess that's how `reselect` works then :).