# Select first row in a named HTML table using JQuery for cloning

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, cloning

Want to copy the first or last row in a specific, named table. I have a large number of columns therefore cloning is the best way to go. [I found this code snippet:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504499/how-to-copy-table-row-with-clone-in-jquery-and-create-new-unique-ids-for-the-con)

```
var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() ​​​{
  $("table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
  }).end().appendTo("table");
  i++;
})​;​
```

My problem is, where do change the selector to specify the table that I am looking for? If you [take a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwdEX/5/) you'll note that adding a row does *add* to only one table, but it appears to clone the row from the first available table. Say I only want to copy rows from `table1` because I am appending to `table1`. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code example with from (#table1) and to (#table2) tables defined.

```
var i = 1;
$("button").click(function() ​​​{
  $("table#table1 tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
  }).end().appendTo("table#table2");
  i++;
})​;​
```

Comment: Thanks a million! Your syntax for finding a specific row in a specific table worked *great*! `$("table#table1 tr:first").clone()`. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Append row for the "table" with id table "table1" :

```
$("button").click(function() ​​​{
  $("#table1 tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
  }).end().appendTo("#table1");
  i++;
})​;​
```

Append row for the "table" with id table "table2" :

```
$("button").click(function() ​​​{
  $("#table2 tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) { return id + i });
  }).end().appendTo("#table2");
  i++;
})​;​
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! The syntax for uniquely identifying a specific row from a specific table is as such: `"table#table1 tr:first"`. Very close! You did put me on the right track.