# Selecting all rows for a give title

Tags: javascript

I have rows like this,

```
<tr onclick="LoadFruit(19210)" data-clisch="12-178" data-catid="88" data-rid="19210" data-start="02/03/2012 00:00:00" data-rstatus="Overdue" data-status="cbOpeks" class="ref" style="display: table-row;">
    <td class="rtddef hov">
        <div style="float:left">Fruitish Fruit 1</div>
        <div class="msb sub"><span style="float:right; padding-right: 5px;">Tmm itee</span>

            <div style="clear:both;"></div> <span style="float:left">Multi Dription 1</span><span style="float:right; padding-right: 5px; color:red">27 M015</span>

        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="rlicd">
        <div title="Weight = 2  Quality = 3">
            <img src="../_layouts/15/images/eControls.WebPart.Details/riskimporange.png" alt="Weight = 2  Quality = 3">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to select all rows of the table and clone them to another table, my goal is to show them, but maybe I need to change ID, however I am having isssue creating select query,

I can do,

```
$("#table tr td[1] div") ... not sure what's next
```

I may use this for cloning [How to Copy Table Row with clone in jquery and create new Unique Ids for the controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504499/how-to-copy-table-row-with-clone-in-jquery-and-create-new-unique-ids-for-the-con) but this is coming after i make a select statement.

Comment: What does *"a give title"* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply select elements by `title`'s attribute value with the following code

```
$("div[title='Weight = 2  Quality = 3']")
```

Comment: it gives me the divs, but I am after rows though, I want to select all rows where div title = this